# Simpler way to paste a texture on lots of Plane faces?

Tags: objects, export, unity

I recently got started with Blender and Unity , and although I know this isn't a 'Unity Stack Exchange', I'm relatively new to all this stuff, and I'm *extremely* new to art and assets.

Basically, I have two questions:

1. When I tried to make a bigger plane/floor, I started by duplicating the small plane to make two small planes, duplicating those two to four etc. until eventually I had a big sized plane made up of ***loads*** of small planes. So when I export them to Unity, I just have massive amounts of planes without the texture I wanted them to have. So I was wondering if there was an easier way to put a texture on loads of different planes.

And

2. To just skip this whole mundane and long process, is there a way to get a texture and duplicate loads next to each other without the hassle of right clicking every plane then doing shift+d and moving them next to each other and repeat.

I'm also using c++, so if there's a code that you guys know that will fix one or both of these issues, I'd be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know anything about unity; but you can duplicate multiple objects while keeping their textures and materials intact by using the array modifier. Alternatively, you can select all the non-textured plains, then select the textured plain at last and press Ctrl+P and select 'material'. This will copy all the materials and textures of the last object selected to the other selected objects.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options depending on the result you want, you can scale one plane to any size you want, then either the texture scales up with it, or you setup the texture to repeat over the plane.

You can use two [array modifiers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/array.html) to duplicate one piece of mesh in two directions. This will duplicate the same piece repeatedly. Then you can apply the modifiers to turn them into a real mesh object, which is an option during export if you only want it that way in unity.

If you want each piece as a separate item in unity, then apply the array modifers, then in edit mode use <kbd>P</kbd>->*By Loose Parts* to break them into multiple objects and <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>*->Origin to Geometry* to put the object centres in the right place.

If you have created multiple planes, select them all <kbd>A</kbd> and press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>*->Material* to set them to use the same material.

To automate tasks in blender, we can use [python v3](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) which is also used to create addons. The [API reference is here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/) as well as an [introduction in the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/scripting/index.html). You can also find plenty of scripts around this site for examples.

And if you need help with unity, they have their [own site](https://answers.unity.com)